# Lucene Query return empty string an index searching

Tags: java, lucene

The following **lucene** query return empty string please help me thank's in advance

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
QueryParser qParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40,"file_name",analyzer);
 Query query = qParser.parse(filename);
```

Comment: I am using Lucene_4x.it is ok.you should check the indexing process.you may not indexing done when you searching.

Comment: indexing was work properly but when i give input to search at that time query will return as empty string.please give any possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating an object of QueryParser you will have to specify the version also.

I will recommend you to use `Version_36` instead.

```
QueryParser qParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36,"file_name",new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
Query query = qParser.parse(filename);
```

Comment: Without saying WHY and stating a source, I can hardly call that an answer though!

Comment: indexing was work properly but when i give input to search at that time query will return as empty string.please give any possible answers

Comment: There is a different pattern for searching if you want to search a single word. I was also stuck at the same place. Will you please tell me which word(or a number of words) do you want to search?

Comment: i want to search a file names

Comment: You mean **FileName** or **File Name**? both words are searched using different techniques.

Comment: In indexing my field name is filename.it's have a some path for that file.i want get get that file path using input.

Comment: @ILikeIOS okay. append **"** **"** before and after query string (in your case it is **file name**). If there is a whitespace in file name, indexer can't give you output, so append **"** **"**.

Comment: I got solution  Thanks  for your help.

Comment: @ILikeIOS From where did you get the solution?

Comment: in your Conversation but small changes happen